# Is “ni faras ambaŭ X kaj Y” an anglicism?

Tags: grammar

I sometimes see people write something along the lines of *ni faras ambaŭ X kaj Y*. This seems like it might be a direct translation of the English construction *we do both X and Y* as a way to emphasise the conjunction. To me it would seem more natural to write this as *ni faras kaj X kaj Y*.

Is the first way also acceptable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I think that is an anglicism in the form you put it. I found this quote in [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#amba%C5%AD):

> «La konj-an uzon de **ambaŭ** en la frazo *ni loĝas en Londono ambaŭ en somero k en vintro* mi trovas tute ne aprobinda» skribis Z.; oni diru: *‘‘kiel en somero, tiel en vintro,* aŭ *«ne nur… sed ankaŭ…»*.

The reason I find it strange to use *ambaŭ* as well is that it need not necessarily be about just two things. For instance:

> Kaj ilia amo, kaj ilia malamo, kaj ilia ĵaluzo jam de longe malaperis.

—[PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/kombinitaj_vortetoj/kaj_kaj.html)

On the other hand, there is an almost identical construction with pretty much the same meaning that is definitely grammatical:

> pli bone estas iri senfila en la ĉielon, ol se ambaŭ, la patro k la filo, iras en la inferon

—[PIV](http://vortaro.net/#amba%C5%AD)

Here *la patro kaj la filo* is an appositive to *ambaŭ*, i.e., it is a specification. This is not equivalent to the form you examplified, because you can apply the *kaj … kaj* construction to the appositive:

*(…) ol se ambaŭ, kaj la patro kaj la filo, iras en la inferon.*

Yet you cannot apply the *kaj … kaj* construction to an already existing *kaj … kaj* construction.

Comment: I totally agree with your explanation. I also checked the use of _ambaŭ_ in recent newspaper articles and could not find a structure like in English 'both ... and', they still follow the traditional style as noted in PAG.
Of course an apposition like in _ol se ambaŭ, la patro k la filo, iras en la inferon_ historically was the base of the English structure, but Esperanto has just not gone the way of English here (yet).

Comment: Indeed, I think the only acceptable form for this is *kaj … kaj* (and the appositional one). I think it is a better form, because it is generalizable to more than two instances. Interesting that the English form indeed comes from the apposition; I only realized that this may be the case while writing the answer!